# GVim can't find plugins on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, vim, gvim

On Windows 10, I have GVim installed to Users\myuser\Vim. I'm using Vundle to handle plugins and it is working fine. But vim isn't finding any of my other plugin files. They're installed (using Vundle) to Users\myuser\Vim\vimfiles\bundle. How can I get vim to find them?

I've already tried adding the plugin directory to my rtp in _vimrc, but no luck. I don't know if this is related, but when I start vim it always starts with the pwd as C:\WINDOWS\System32 rather than the directory Vim is installed in.

Here is the opening part of my _vimrc:

```
set nocompatible 
"source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim 
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim 

au! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC nested source $MYVIMRC 

filetype off                  " required 

set rtp+=%HOMEPATH%\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\Vundle.vim 
set rtp+=%HOMEPATH%\Vim\vimfiles 
call vundle#begin() 
let g:vundle#bundle_dir='vimfiles\bundle' 

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' 

" basic editing functions------------------------------------ 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-abolish' 
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion' 
Bundle 'camelcasemotion' 
Bundle 'rename' 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-repeat' 
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter' 
Bundle 'surround.vim' 
Bundle 'gundo' 
Bundle 'YankRing.vim' 
Bundle 'vim-multiple-cursors' 
Bundle 'guifontpp.vim' 
" gui--------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'vim-airline/vim-airline' 
Bundle 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes' 
Bundle 'qpkorr/vim-bufkill' 
Bundle 'drmikehenry/vim-fontsize' 
" project management------------------------------------------ 
Bundle 'xolox/vim-session' 
Bundle 'TaskList.vim' 
" code completion and symbols--------------------------------- 
Bundle 'snipmate' 
Bundle 'supertab' 
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic' 
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar' 
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe' 
"Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim' 
Bundle 'Shougo/context_filetype.vim' 
" utilities--------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'tlib' 
Bundle 'AnsiEsc.vim' 
Bundle 'vim-misc' 
Bundle 'WebAPI.vim' 
" search and navigation--------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'Shougo/unite.vim' 
Bundle 'ack.vim' 
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim' 
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree' 
Bundle 'voogle' 
" filetypes and code hilighting--------------------------------- 
Bundle 'SyntaxRange' 
" markdown-------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc' 
Bundle 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-after' 
Bundle 'vim-pandoc/vim-markdownfootnotes' 
Bundle 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax' 
" latex---------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'jcf/vim-latex' 
" python--------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'pychimp' 
Bundle 'klen/python-mode' 
Bundle 'monotasker/vim_web2py_syntax' 
" javascript------------------------------------------------------ 
Bundle 'itspriddle/vim-jquery' 
" html/xml-------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'closetag.vim' 
Bundle 'XML-Folding' 
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'} 
Bundle 'bonsaiben/bootstrap-snippets' 
" css--------------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'vim-less' 
Bundle 'vim-lesscss' 
Bundle 'less-syntax' 
Bundle 'css_color.vim' 
" svg--------------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'svg.vim' 
" colorschemes --------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'chriskempson/base16-vim' 
"Bundle 'solarized' 
Bundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes' 
Bundle 'vividchalk.vim' 
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-distinguished' 
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized' 
" color utilities --------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'colorv' 
Bundle 'galaxy.vim' 
Bundle 'guicolorscheme.vim' 
Bundle 'KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim' 
" version control --------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-git' 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive' 
" snippets ---------------------------------------------------------- 
Bundle 'monotasker/web2py-snippets' 

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line 
call vundle#end()            " required 
syntax on 
filetype plugin indent on    " required 
set nospell 

" UTILITY MAPPINGS 
" ========================================================================== 
let maplocalleader = '\' 
nnoremap ; : 
vnoremap ; :
```

Comment: They're installed (using Vundle) to `Users\myuser\vimfiles\bundle` and `%HOMEPATH%\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\Vundle.vim` are different ... the 2nd one has ``\Vim\`` in it ...

Comment: Sorry @DavidPostill, that was a typo on my part. I've fixed it in the question now. Vundle is indeed installing them to Users\myuser\Vim\vimfiles\bundle